# Copiar texto oculto igual whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ola, uma situação que preciso fazer e não consegui utilizamos métodos normais como "display: none, user-select: all" etc, é copiar textos ocultos ou em tags ocultas.

Se abrir o whatsapp web, verá que ao copiar uma mensagem, o NOME + DATA HORA aparece na frente de cada mensagem copiada. Esta seria a intenção de ser feita.

Temos um chat hoje, porem exibimos nome + data e hora, e isto acaba ficando visualmente estranho em nosso sistema. Gostaria-mos de esconder isto e exibir apenas ao copiar.

Alguem tem ideia de qual a possibilidade ou como fazer algo deste genero?

Comment: Oi talvez esse link [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089713/modify-clipboard-content-after-copy-event-javascript-jquery) te ajude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma *hakezinho* que vc pode fazer... só tem um "problema" a pessoa tem que copiar o texto até o final, se ela não pegar o texto todo não vai pegar a data e hora que estão ocultos no fim do texto... Tipo, se a pessoa pegar só um pedaço do meio da mensagem não vai pegar a data e a hora. Veja o gif abaixo para entender melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu fiz foi colocar a cor transparente e diminuir o tamanho do texto com o `letter-spacing`. Então se a pessoa selecionar tudo arrastando, ou clicando 3x vai pegar a ata/hora, se seleciona do final pro início pega tb. Só não pega data/hora se a pessoa só seleciona um pedaço do início ou do meio do texto.

Teste vc mesmo...

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box .txt {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box .data {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    letter-spacing: -7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span class="txt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, dignissimos.
        <span class="data"> 24/08/19 8:20</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Ocultar texto é considerado uma prática de ***black hat*** pelo Google, não use isso para ocultar *key words* e outras coisas, o Google pode te penalizar por isso... Utilize apenas no seu sistema de chat se desejar.

Comment: Perfeito! O do Whatsapp tambem não copia caso pegar metade / parte do texto, apenas selecionando tudo. Não temos nenhum site publico ou que precisamos de importância do Google, todos nossos sistemas são internos e acessados localmente pela equipe.

Comment: @OtavioFausto que bom que ajudou ai, se ficou igual o do whatsapp da bom de mais então haha

Comment: Não ficou igual kkk porque pelo o que eu entendi eles usam javascript que substitui, porem ficou parecido a questão da funcionalidade, ja servindo para o objetivo. Como é interno, não precisa de nada muito profissional.